# Taylor expansion of $f(x(t),y(t))$ around the point $(x_0,y_0)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

My main question is basically whether the fact that both inputs depend on $t$ is an issue? Because if $x$ changes then $t$ must have changed and thus $y$ is likely to have changed. So would we need total derivatives when doing the taylor expansion or are partial derivatives still okay?

An example to illustrate my confusion: 
Let 
$$f(x(t),y(t)) = x(t) + y(t)$$ and $x(t) = t^2$, $y(t) = t^3)$. For simplicity lets just consider the expansion to first order, around $(x_0,y_0)$, with $x_0 = x(t_0), y_0 = y(t_0)$:
$$ f(x(t),y(t)) \approx x_0 + y_0 + f_x (x - x_0) + f_y(y-y_0)  = x_0 + y_0 + (x-x_0) + (y-y_0)$$
is that correct? (omitting some $O(\cdot)$ terms).

Thanks

Comment: the $O(.)$ terms are indeed useful for convincing yourself (for proving) that it is correct... so don't omit them next time ! and don't forget that if $h(t)$ is only differentiable (but we don't know if it is $C^2$, or even $C^1$) then $h(x)= h(x_0) + (x-x_0) h'(x_0) + o(|x-x_0|)$ when $[x-x_0| \to 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to 
set $g\left(t\right)=f\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right)$,
then 
$$
g\left(t\right)\approx g\left(t_{0}\right)+g'\left(t_{0}\right)\left(t-t_{0}\right)
$$
where 
$$
g'\left(t_{0}\right)=\left(\partial_{x}f\right)\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)x'\left(t_{0}\right)+\left(\partial_{y}f\right)\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)x'\left(t_{0}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you. I think you are correct, and I find this answer quite clear, so I will accept it.